# Django Reverse Relation Serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, serialization, django-serializer

I am trying to create a project for self learning and right now, I am stuck at this point.

Its an event planner and each event will have meat. Organizer of the event can select or create new meat types for his event. Once the event created, guests can select their preferred meat type from the selection pool which the organizer picked.

For example, as an organizer I can say I will have "Chicken", "Turkey", and "Beef" from a `MeatType` table which has "Chicken", "Turkey" and "Pork" . (Organizer will create a new `MeatType` and select it for his event)

So I have 3 Django model related for this specific problem.

**Event model**:

```
class Event(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(_('Event name'), max_length=255)
   capacity = models.IntegerField(_('Capacity'), null=True)
   address = models.CharField(_('Address'), max_length=255)
   date = models.DateTimeField(_('Event Date'), db_index=True)

   organizer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_('Organizer'), related_name='events',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Meat Type model**:

```
class MeatType(models.Model):
   """
   A model just to hold meat type names on the database.
   This model will only have a "name" field which represents the Meat Type.
   For example, "Chicken" or "Beef"
   """
   name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255)
```

and **Available Meat Type Model**:

```
class AvailableMeatType(models.Model):
    """
    Available meat types for the event selected by Organizer
    """
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, verbose_name=_('Event'), related_name='available_meat_types',
                          on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    meat_type = models.ForeignKey(MeatType, verbose_name=_('Meat Type'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

According to this structure, to create an event, organizer should send a request looking like this:

```
    {
       "name": "Team BBQ",
       "capacity": 10,
       "address": "Down Town",
       "date": "2019-02-01T18:00",
       "available_meat_type_ids": [
           1, 
           2, 
           3
       ]    
    }
```

Where 1 , 2 and 3 is the `Meat Type` ids but will create `Available Meat Type` objects like: { 123, 1 } , { 123, 2} , { 123, 3} where 123 is the created event id

** My Serializers **

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A serializer class for creating and listing events
    """
    organizer = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    available_meat_type_ids = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
    many=True,
    read_only=True
)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'capacity',
            'address',
            'date',
            'organizer',
            'available_meat_type_ids'
        )
        read_only_fields = ('organizer', )

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Create available meat type object
        """
        # I dont know what to do here
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def validate_date(date):
        # Date of the event can not be on the past
        if date < timezone.now():
            raise Exception("Date of the new event can not be on the past.")
        return date


class CreateAvailableMeatTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A serializer for available meat type request.
    """
    event = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(required=True, queryset=Event.objects)
    meat_type = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(required=True, queryset=MeatType.objects)

    class Meta:
        model = AvailableMeatType
        fields = (
            'id',
        )
```

I dont know how to make it work. I tried to search online, but couldnt find anything that helps.

How can I create available meat type objects from the meat type ids that I receive in Event creation request?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply do it by this:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    organizer = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    available_meat_type_ids = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True
    )
    meat_id = serailizers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'capacity',
            'address',
            'date',
            'organizer',
            'available_meat_types',
            'meat_id'
        )
        read_only_fields = ('organizer', )
        write_only_fields = ('meat_id',)

    def create(self, validate_data):
      meat_id = validate_data.pop('meat_id')
      event = Event.objects.create(**validate_data)
      AvailableMeatType.objects.create(event=event, meat_type_id=meat_id)
      return event
```

For more details please check the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) on PrimaryKeyRelatedField.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but then I got "TypeError at /api/events/
'AvailableMeatType' instance expected, got <MeatType: rind>" @ruddra

Comment: The Problem is, I need to give Meat Type ids and create Available Meat Types objects

Comment: I assumed that you wanted to write available_meat_types on the serializer field definitions. But there are no meat_id s in the validated data in create

Comment: I have added a new field in the serializer. But I forgot to add it to the `fields` list. Please see the updated answer